# How to change position of HTML elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

I have following HTML:

```
<div id="ServiceProvider" class="main_filter" name="filterDiv">
    <div class="filter_chkbox_div" style="display:none">
       <label class="ATT">AT&amp;T</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_chkbox_div" style="display:none">
       <label class="CABLEONE">Cable One</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_chkbox_div" style="display:none">          
       <label class="CABLEONEv6">Cable Onev6</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_chkbox_div" style="display:none">
        <label class="CHARTER">Charter</label>
    </div> 
</div>
```

At runtime I display only those labels that I receive in my array `providerCodes`

**jQuery code**

```
for (var i = 0; i < providerCodes.length; i++) {
    var providerCheckBox = $("#" + providerCodes[i]);
    if (providerCheckBox.length > 0) {
        $(providerCheckBox).parent().show();
    }
}
```

Now I want to position these labels in accordance to the order I receive in `providerCodes`. For Example, if `providerCodes` array contain `CHARTER` on 0th index and `CABLEONE` on 1st index,I want to change the position of these labels accordingly. Currently, it will show `CABLEONE` first and then `CHARTER`. How can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: can share providerCodes ??

Comment: @DharaParmar for the example I stated above,providerCodes array contains class names of labels.In this case it contains `["CHARTER","CABLEONE"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this (provided that you have the div selector for the container):

```
var containerSelector = $("<container-selector>");
for (var i = 0; i < providerCodes.length; i++) {
   var providerCheckBox = $("#" + providerCodes[i]);
   if (providerCheckBox.length > 0) {
       $(providerCheckBox).parent().show().detach().appendTo(containerSelector);
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `containerSelector`? Please check my edited post, maybe you mean to refer to the div I just added with class `main_filter`?

Comment: yes exactly the div that is containing all the inner divs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.clone()` to first clone all the hidden `div` then `empty` the container then loop through your input array and attache those back to container and make them visible. At last attach all remaining `div` whose `class` is not the part of input array:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var providerCodes = ["CHARTER","CABLEONE "] ;
  var clonnedObject = $(".mycontainer").clone();
  $(".mycontainer").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < providerCodes.length; i++) {
        var providerCheckBox = $(clonnedObject).find("." + providerCodes[i]);
        if (providerCheckBox.length > 0) {
            $(providerCheckBox).parent().appendTo(".mycontainer").show();
        }
    }
  $(clonnedObject).children().appendTo(".mycontainer");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="filter_chkbox_div" style="display:none">
   <label class="ATT">AT&amp;T</label>
</div>
<div class="filter_chkbox_div" style="display:none">
   <label class="CABLEONE">Cable One</label>
</div>
<div class="filter_chkbox_div" style="display:none">          
   <label class="CABLEONEv6">Cable Onev6</label>
</div>
<div class="filter_chkbox_div" style="display:none">
    <label class="CHARTER">Charter</label>
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To reorder the elements we will get they index into the array and put them before this index of `.filter_chkbox_div`

```
var providerCodes = ["CABLEONEv6","CABLEONE"];
for (var i = 0; i < providerCodes.length; i++) {
  var providerCheckBox = $("." + providerCodes[i]);
  if (providerCheckBox.length > 0) {
    $('.filter_chkbox_div').eq(i).before(providerCheckBox.parent());
    providerCheckBox.parent().show();
  }
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/srkbcdox/